# In VS2015, how do I disable Step Into for auto-implemented properties?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I've just started using Visual Studio 2015 and found that it behaves differently to VS2012/VS2013 when debugging auto-implemented properties.

Say I have a property defined in a class:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

ie. an auto-implemented property where the getter and setter are effectively generated by the compiler.

I may refer to this property later on, as part of a method call for example:

```
{
    DoSomeStuff(MyProperty);
}
```

If I want to debug the call to `DoSomeStuff` and put a breakpoint on that line, then wait for it to be hit and F11 to Step Into the call, the VS2015 debugger now steps into the getter for `MyProperty` (in previous versions, for auto-implemented properties, it would just ignore the getters and setters).

I found a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/14/set-breakpoints-on-auto-implemented-properties-with-visual-studio-2015/) that describes the ability to put breakpoints on auto getters & setters as a new feature, and I can see how that may be useful in some cases. However, in my case I am not interested in breakpointing or stepping into these methods, particularly as our codebase has many auto-implemented properties and access to them is often nested (eg. `DoSomeStuff(X.Y.Z)`).

In short, is it possible to disable the new Step Into behaviour for auto-implemented properties in VS2015, and if so, how?

(I noticed a "Step over properties and operators" checkbox in the Debugging Options, but I don't want to step over all property getters/setters, just those for auto-implemented properties.)

Comment: Usually, it is best to `Step over properties` almost all the time and only step in when you actually need to debug a particular property code. Contextual menu have many options related to stepping.

Comment: Vote on this issue on Visual Studio Developer Community. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Step-into-properties-option-should-skip/578674?space=8&q=auto+properties+debugger

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to the VS2015 options -> debugging -> general and tick "Step over properties and operators".

Comment: I've edited my answer to tell you how to change the general behavior.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer, even though it's a bit of a nuclear one: prevents the Step Into not just for auto-implemented properties but for *all* properties. Very annoying that there is no way to prevent one and not the other, particularly as this is a change in behaviour from earlier VS versions.

Comment: Didn't work for VS2022

Answer (score 2):

just add the DebuggerStepThrough attribute to your function / class..

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public class DontDebugInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: This works for only classes. @Kinetic's answer is correct for skipping property setters.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017:

Pause the debugger on the line of the method call -> Right click the method -> Step Into Specific -> [choose your method from the list].

This is not a configuration robust solution, but rather an action you should do each time you want to enter a method and avoid properties stepping into.